# cut string on last delimiter

Tags: shell, cut

I have a filename like `a.b.c.txt`, I want this string to be split as

```
string1=a.b.c
string2=txt
```

Basically I want to split filename and its extension. I used `cut` but it splits as `a,b,c` and `txt`. I want to cut the string on the last delimiter.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
 #For Filename
 echo "a.b.c.txt" | rev | cut -d"." -f2-  | rev
 #For extension
 echo "a.b.c.txt" | rev | cut -d"." -f1  | rev
```

Comment: Beauty of code!

Comment: old school unix classic way

Comment: rev is really smart

Answer (score 21):

There are many tools to do this.

As you were using `cut` :

```
$ string1="$(cut -d. -f1-3 <<<'a.b.c.txt')"
$ string2="$(cut -d. -f4 <<<'a.b.c.txt')"
$ echo "$string1"
a.b.c
$ echo "$string2"
txt
```

I would have used parameter expansion (if the shell supports it) :

```
$ name='a.b.c.txt'
$ string1="${name%.*}"
$ string2="${name##*.}"
$ echo "$string1"
a.b.c
$ echo "$string2"
txt
```

Comment: the bash solution is elegant.

Comment: the _cut_ one does only work with a fixed number of periods!

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "a.b.c.txt" | cut -d. -f1-3
```

`cut` command will delimit `.` and will give you 4 factors (`a`, `b`, `c`, `txt`). Above command will print factor 1 to 3 (included).

Or:

```
echo "a.b.c.txt" | cut -d -f-3
```

Above command will print factor 1 till 3 (included).